# Accessing variables in MainActivity from AsynTask job

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, static-variables

My app fetching data from an API and adding it to `ArrayList<String>` to parse it and show it to the user in the UI.
I made the ArrayList `static` then I access it like `MainActivity.arrayList.add(link);` but I was told that `static variables` are evil and I should not use them, Also if I used setter and getter it has to be `static` to access it from another class.
I am thinking if sending everything I need to modify it to the `AsyncTask` then return it from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` with the results but I think it's not the best way to do it.
Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice and the preferred way to access Activity's variables from an AsyncTask is, accessing them at onProgressUpdate and the onPostExecute methods. Because Activities, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute runs on UI thread but doInBackground method runs on a separate thread. And accessing a variable from a separate thread can be painful. Also static variable definition must be well designed because all instances of a class, uses same static variable instance.

You should better add a callback interface to your asynctask to handle its result.

Let me give an example;

I've copied below asynctask from [Google's site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). And modified by adding an interface:

```
private static class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     interface OnDownloadListener {
         void onDownloadFinished(long bytes);
         void onDownloadProgressUpdate(int progress);
     }

     private OnDownloadListener mDownloadListener;
     public DownloadFilesTask (OnDownloadListener onDownloadListener) {
         mOnDownloadListener = onDownloadListener;
     }

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         mOnDownloadListener.onDownloadProgressUpdate(progress);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         mOnDownloadListener.onDownloadFinished(result);
     }
 }
```

At your activity, implement the interface, and send you activity to asynctask's constructor:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements OnDownloadListener {

  // activity's logic here

  // create an instance of the asyncTask
  DownloadFilesTask downloadFilesTask = new DownloadFilesTask(this);


  // OnDownloadListener interface implementation
  void onDownloadFinished(long bytes) {
      // handle asyncTasks onPostExecute method, you can reach non static variables here.     
  }

  void onDownloadProgressUpdate(int progress) {
      // handle asyncTasks onProgressUpdate method, you can reach non static variables here.
  }
}
```

As far as I know this is the simplest and the preferred way to handle asynctask's result.

Answer (score -1):

As of July 25, 2019
This is my solution:

```
    MainActivity.java:
    public static String name = "";

    --------------------

    AsyncTask.java
    //import your main activity java
    import static com.example.test.testproject.MainActivity.*;  

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       //get your json here...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
       super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       // process your json here

       // Then pass the json value to your main variable
       MainActivity.name = JsonObject.get("name");
    }

 Practically you only need two things
     1. public static on MainActivity
     2. Pass your local variable to the MainActivity variable, inside onPostExecute method.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really bad and breaks many best-practices about Android. Please read some guides on how to use AsyncTasks https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask (or better, don't use it at all. AsyncTask have so many limitation like 1) no orientation-change support, 2) no ability to cancel network calls, 3) as well as no easy way to make API calls in parallel.)

Comment: other things to remember: 4) don't include static variables in an Activity, 5) don't statically import an Activity, 6) don't process JSON on the UI-thread, 7) Don't assume the MainActivity is still alive after doInBackground